# Finding the inverse function.

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x)=\frac{(1-\sqrt{x})}{(1+\sqrt{x})}
$$
Anyone can guide me for doing this? I understand the meaning of inverse but somehow this question puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that $f$ is defined for $x\ge0$ and that $f(x)>-1$ and then we solve for $x$ the equation

$$f(x)=y\iff \frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}=y\iff\sqrt x(y+1)=(1-y)\iff x=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2$$
so

$$f^{-1}(x)=\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2$$

Comment: how do u get from second step to third step, don understand

Comment: The fraction gives $1-\sqrt x=y(1+\sqrt x)$ then we develop and we factor with $\sqrt x$.

Comment: what I did is that let f^-1(x)=y >>f(y)=x then (1-√y)/(1+√y)=x then Idk how to proceed alrdy.

Comment: understand alrdy thx!!!!!!can you vote for me xd?